# JavaScript code not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, safari, location-href

I have three pages:

***Step1.php -> step2.php -> step3.php***

As it shows, after submitting the **step1.php** it will go to **step2.php**

In **step2.php** there is  JavaScript on the bottom, and it will automatically redirect to **step3.php** after 2 seconds.

```
<input type="hidden" name="queryString" id="queryString" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>"/>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function redirection() {
        var queryString =document.getElementById("queryString").value;
        var reloadURL = "step3.php?"+queryString;
        location.href = reloadURL;
    }

        setTimeout("redirection()", 2000);
</script>
```

This forward flow is working in every other browser.

Now I am just clicking the back button of the browser from `` `step3.php `` page. Then it comes to **step2.php** and after 2 seconds it will go to **step3.php**.

But in Safari it doesn't work, it will get stuck on **step2.php**.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webkit browser are caching the last state of the last pages, as it was, when you left. Have you tried to use a meta tag instead. Don't know if this works, but worth a try:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="2;url=page2.php">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this link it might be usefull http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php as mostly problem lies in passing variable to addressbar from java script